# How can we use AIML for making a chatbot?

Tags: aiml

Can we give random responses for a single question in AIML. For "Hi", I need random replies like "hey", "hello", "hi", etc.

Comment: Your title and content are quite different. Which one are you after? For the content question the answer is "yes", as a quick internet search will show. It will also show how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AIML can be used for making chatbots. But you have to make templates for all possible questions user could possibly ask. Here is an example for AIML random responses

```
 <pattern>HI</pattern>
   <template>
     <random>
        <li> Hello! </li>
        <li> Hi </li>
        <li> Hey </li>
     </random>
```